# New error - Pending Update of Snap Store

Tags: 22.04, snap-store

Both Laptop and Desktop running Unbutu 22.04.01 updated from 20.04 have started showing intermittent messages saying "Pending update of App Store and something about stopping the app (which isn't running anyway - or at least isn't appearing in System Monitor) within 12 or 13 days "to avoid disruptions"

This only started about 2 weeks ago

What's going on???? WHat does itr mean??? How do you stop something that isn't running.

Personally I never install software from Snaps, although I undrestand some Ubuntu bundled software like Firefox is a snap - but I don't use Firefox so perhaps it doesn't matter.

Can I just ignore this annoyance or will I get "disruptions" whatever that means?

Answer (score 1):

That isn't an error, but an information that action has to be taken to activate an update to snap-store.

Updates to applications running under snapd cannot be applied if the app is active. The easiest / only way is to kill the mentioned app: `pkill snap-store` .. prefix with `sudo` if the app is owned by an other user than you.

Then run `sudo snap refresh` to do the update.

Similar will work for other snap apps, like mozilla and so on.